# SQl Server User Instance in Console Application

Tags: sql-server-express, console-application, user-instance

Is it possible to user SQL Server Express User Instance databases with Console applications or do they only work in Web projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing specific "web" about user instances; it should work the same from console, web, winform or wpf...

The only difference is that the Express IDE may not have options to set it up for you... but that doesn't matter. Create the database, and just hook it up with the connection strings manually.

---

I just tried it (by adding an mdb + ldf to a console app in Express) and it worked fine; it even added the connection strings (in user-instance mode) for me. That *might* be because I have additional VS tools installed, but it worked...

At runtime, it doesn't know whether it came from Express, Pro, or Team Suite.

Comment: That's my understanding also.